# ItemsControl with multiple DataTemplates and a generic header for each item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a bunch of relatively simple viewmodels. They all implement a common interface:

```
public interface IComponent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool IsExpanded { get; }
    string Header { get; }
    ICommand AddComponentCommand { get; }
    ICommand DeleteComponentCommand { get; }
}
```

I want all of my viewmodels to have their own `DataTemplate` so that they are laid out correctly. I also want the controls to have a header with an add and delete button. If add has been clicked, the control has content and it will be "visible" by use of an expander.

I managed to get different `DateTemplates` working with an `ItemsControl`.

C# Main viewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<IComponent> _components = new ObservableCollection<IComponent>();
public ObservableCollection<IComponent> Components
{
    get => _components;
    set => SetField(ref _components, value);
}
```

xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Components}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <!-- FailCost -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CarViewModel}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddComponentCommand}"/>
                    <Button Content="Del" Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCommand}"/>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Car.Brand}"/>
                    </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:PersonViewModel}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddComponentCommand}"/>
                    <Button Content="Del" Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCommand}"/>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
                    </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

</ItemsControl>
```

However I now have to repeat the header components for every `DataTemplate`. I have the common functionality in the interface, I don't want to repeat the add/delete buttons and the headertext for each item. I've been googling for a while but I feel like I miss the vocab for this problem because I can't find simular cases.

How can I add a generic header to all items in my `ItemsControl`.

For clarity: I don't need a `HeaderItemsControl`, I don't need my `ItemsControl` to have a header. I need the items in my `ItemsControl` to all have the same header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="template" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddComponentCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Del" Command="{Binding DeleteComponentCommand}"/>
            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CarViewModel}">
    <UserControl Template="{StaticResource template}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Car.Brand}"/>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:PersonViewModel}">
    <UserControl Template="{StaticResource template}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
    </UserControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.